# How to buy an ecofriendly printer that accepts refilled cartridges?

Tags: green-it, waste-minimisation

I have a HP Deskjet printer that does not allow me to use refilled cartridges, therefore every time it runs out of ink I need to buy a new cartridge, which implies a lot of waste.

I would like to know how to buy a printer that does not present this issue, and in general that has a low environmental impact.

Comment: I'm not saying that you're wrong, but **how** do you know that the printer won't allow refilled cartridges?  Is it just that the cartridges it comes with don't have any kind of refill holes/ports?  I don't think my printer's cartridges are officially refillable, but with a small drill bit, a syringe, a hot glue gun, and some bottles of ink (bought on eBay), I've refilled my ink many, many times with the original cartridges.

Comment: The thing is that the printer has memory of the cartridges that have been used. The printer displays the approximate level of ink in the cartridge, once they are empty, the printer doesn't allow you to print with theme, even if you refill theme. I've found several tutorials to reset the cartridges, but none of the tricks has worked for me, that is why I have to buy new cartridges every time. I've read that this is the new system HP uses in its printers to avoid the use of refilled cartridges, a practice not eco-friendly at all.

Comment: Ouch.  That's evil of HP :(

Answer (score 7):

While you may not be able to get them refilled yourself, HP does run a recycling program for them, free of charge: [HP Product Return and Recycling](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/hp-information/environment/).

Didn't look in to whether they simply refill and resell them or if they actually melt the cartridges down and start from scratch... either way it's better than the landfill. Unfortunately, you're still stuck buying new cartridges.

Lexmark <s>runs</s> ran a similar program that rewards you with a free cartridge for every 5 you send in to be recycled... better than getting nothing in return. They also give you a free one for every 5 you buy. **UPDATE:** [Lexmark has ended their rewards program](https://www.lexmark.com/en_us/products/supplies-and-accessories/lexmark-rewards-po/toner-rewards-programs.html):

> Thank you for your interest in the Toner Rewards program. At this time, Lexmark is no longer accepting new enrollments into the program.

As far as companies go, HP appears to be near setting the bar for environmentally friendly electronics: [Greenpeace Guide to Greener Electronics 2017](http://www.greenpeace.org/international/en/campaigns/climate-change/cool-it/Campaign-analysis/Guide-to-Greener-Electronics/).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are some printers which are compatible with a [Continuous Ink System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_ink_system).

Today I bought one of these for my printer, so I can't tell you right know if this system works or not.

I don't want to make publicity for a particular product, but I think if you [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=cis%20#q=buy%20ink%20ciss%20system) a bit you will find some stores and see in which printers this can be used.

Answer (score 3):

I have been using a CISS (Continuous Ink Supply System) for some time on my Epson RX610. Purchased through eBay. It is a cheap investment. Be aware of the following regarding inks: [the most important part of the whole printing system is really the quality of the inks and not so much the hardware](https://web.archive.org/web/20121206030501/http://www.cnet.com.au/photo-printing-when-inks-aint-inks-240004041.htm)

Occasionally the printer "Cannot recognise" the non-genuine ink cartridge, but remove and re-insert fixes that.

Having had the success with the Epson, I purchased a CISS for the HP Officejet we have at our Men's Shed. It too works fine, although the printer recognises that "counterfeit" cartridges have been fitted.

Before rushing out and buying a CISS, please view a Youtube video showing the installation of one - preferably into your printer model.